# Vertically align text within div element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this question has been asked to death but nothing through searching has worked for me.

You know the deal, I have a div element that I need to vertically align text in but nothing has worked (position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-x;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;etc., etc.)

Here is what I am working with (sorry for the inline CSS).  Anyway, the I would use line-height but the text can be one or two lines.  It should vertical align with the image which is always max-height of 30px (30x50).

```
 <div style="margin:0 0 10px 0;padding:10px;border:2px solid #606060;background-color:#2b2b2b;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;">
 <div style="float:left;width:55px;height:40px;">
 <a href="link"><img style="max-width:50px;border:1px solid #ffb92c;" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div style="float:right;width:155px;font-size:0.7em;height:40px;">
 <a href="link">This is the text to vertically align</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Must you use inline `CSS`? Makes it a pain to answer...

Comment: No not at all, I plan on converting all this to reg CSS once I figure it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is from [here](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) and should work for all browsers.

```
<div style="margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #606060; background-color: #2b2b2b;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 55px; height: 40px;">
        <a href="link">
            <img style="max-width: 50px; border: 1px solid #ffb92c;" src="image.jpg"
                alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 155px; font-size: 0.7em; height: 40px; display: table; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="#position: absolute; #top: 50%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <div style="#position: relative; #top: -50%;">
                <a href="link">This is the text to vertically align</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Image and text both are not properly vertically aligned

Comment: @Tom It's because of the other margins or paddings of your html fragment. Anyway, if you have some dynamic sized div and want to align content vertically the link gives the only cross-browser solution present. Other solutions either works for static height or only for some browser and for some version greater than bla bla...

Comment: @Yigit I actually got it to work.  It wasn't the text that wasn't aligning correctly, it was the image.  If I wrap the image in the same div tags as I do the text, it all lines up.

Answer (score 9):

One other thing you can do. If it's only one line of text in the div you can use `line-height`

example

```
div {
    line-height:40px;
}
```

Comment: It could be either one or two lines.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/5u9HY/

Use `fixed height` instead of `padding` in main div. and use line height for left & right Divs

Comment: Line height will only work if it's one line of text, it could be one or two.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean version of the solution

```
<div style="background: yellow">
<div style="width: 155px; font-size: 0.7em; height: 40px; display: table; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div style="">
            <a href="link">This is the text to vertically align</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5y4Nb/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a common float issue which can be fixed with a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) or, like i did in the following code snippet, with a fixed height of the wrapper.

I also sat an `line-height` of the floating divs and made it a little wider.

Take a look at this:

```
 <div style="margin:0 0 10px 0;padding:10px;border:2px solid #606060;background-color:#2b2b2b;-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px;height:40px">  <div style="float:left;width:55px;height:40px;">  <a href="link"><img style="max-width:50px;border:1px solid #ffb92c;" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>  </div>  <div style="float:right;width:185px;font-size:0.7em;height:40px;line-height:40px">  <a href="link">This is the text to vertically align</a>  </div>  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YqxPZ/3/

Comment: Your fix has some bugs. Image and text both are not properly vertically aligned to each other and even within a div.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work if the text is long enough to be two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Is you need to show only a few lines of a very long text, here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7rvcaa0/7/). Adjust height according as needed.

```
    .container-text {
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    overflow-y:hidden;    
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```