# Align text vertically centered- In all IEs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a text-control in Div. I want to place the text aligned vertically centered of div.

The div has following styling:

```
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: Left;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 80px;
 padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

Problem:

It aligns text as expected in IE8, but fails in IE7 and IE6.

Anyway to fix it, so it works alright in all IEs.

Comment: div contains single line or multiple lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679966/vertically-align-text-within-div-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679966/vertically-align-text-within-div-element)

Comment: Div Contains multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

use

```
position:relative top:50% top:-50%
```

for ie 6/7 , this might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height and position to the class

```
line-height: 80px;
position: absolute;
```

Finally your CSS looks like:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 14px;
height: 80px;
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid;
line-height: 80px;
position: absolute;
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/4qnwk/2/)**

Comment: This doesnot work when my text has line breaks. It doesnot show the text in line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try line-height: 80px, I think it will work.

Comment: Doesnot work. Div is supposed to have any number lines possible within specified height. But line-height: 80 shows only one line text.