# How to vertically align text in a div

Tags: css

Hello I simply want to align my text vertically in a div

please find the live example http://jsfiddle.net/fb48n/
can any one tell me how to align vertically ?

```
<div class="Heading">Upload a file</div>
```

css

```
.Heading{
   height: 62px;
   vertical-align: 50%;background: #D46023;
   padding: 5px 5px;
   color: white;
   font-size: 18pt;
   font-weight: normal !important;
   display: block;
   text-align: left
}
```

Comment: sorry even if you apply vertical-align: middle or any thing  it does not work :-(

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6680148/760489

Comment: no i dont want to handle it through positioning is there no simple way ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set your `line-height` the same as the container box.

```
line-height:62px;
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb48n/7/).

Comment: No Line-height doesnot work as i have 3 columns side by side , in 3rd column heading text due to large title goes to 2nd line and if i apply line height title cuts

see http://jsfiddle.net/fb48n/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just set div display to table cell `display: table-cell` and give it `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: It was good answer but another problem appears after displaying it as table-cell. the background color got shrinked to heading area only

Answer (score 0):

MarcoK is right! You just have to set the line-height as below:

```
.Heading {
  line-height:62px;
  background: #D46023;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

Div is already a block and text-align is set to left by default.

Olivier